# Fetch row to column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a scenario like this.
Need to display the Type and Amount in the format.
Need help

```
ParamID  ProblemID  Data  FIELDID
 1247176  285135  2.Materials  283
 1247177  285135  2557.8  284
 1247314  285132  2.Materials  283
 1247315  285132  2889.1  284
 1247320  284848  2.Materials  283
 1247321  284848  2202.5  284
 1247326  285088  2.Materials  283
 1247327  285088  2139  284
 1247332  285085  2.Materials  283
 1247333  285085  2139  284
 1247338  285081  2.Materials  283
 1247339  285081  2408  284
 1247374  285134  2.Materials  283
 1247375  285134  2869  284
 1247458  286204  3.Travel  283
 1247459  286204  375  284
```

I want the output as below

```
ProblemID  Type  Amount
 285135  2.Materials  2557.8
 285132  2.Materials  2889.1
 284848  2.Materials  2202.5
 285088  2.Materials  2139
 285085  2.Materials  2139
 285081  2.Materials  2408
 285134  2.Materials  2869
 286204  3.Travel 375
```

This is what I have tried

```
select ProblemID, Data as Type, (select data from table where paramid = paramid+1) as Amount from table where FieldID = 283
```

Comment: describe your output requirement , take screen shot of table structure n attach that

Comment: No, describe what you have already implemented and what your problem is with it. SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Updated the code block.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are getting problem in fetching alternate records under column `data`. I can help you in that.

Use the following query:

```
select ProblemID, 
case 
when MOD(ParamID, 2) = 0 then Data 
end as Type, 
case 
when MOD(ParamID, 2) = 1 then Data 
end as Amount  from table
group by ProblemID
```

I haven't checked it's output; But it shall solve your problem of fetching alternate records under a same column with different column_names.

If you are having any small displaying issue then you have to adjust it here and there :)

Comment: Hi Avidan,<br> FieldID is the Reference. Type and Amount come one after other. its not the case always <b>Type paramid is even or odd</b>.<br> Some times its even and some times its odd. I can't do mod function.

Comment: Buddy; `Type` is not even or odd but `ParamID` is. It may be your primary key with auto increment. Plz check and confirm. I have used `ParamID` to fetch alternate records from `Data` column and not `Data` column itself

Comment: To fetch data in the third column i need to increment the paramid value

Comment: ParamID is autoincrement field. Here in the Example you can see ParamID of fieldID 283 as even number. But in real case some are even and some are odd.

Comment: aren't your alternate `ParamID`s are even and alternate `ParamID`s are odd? If it is an autoincrement field...
Those should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProblemID, Data AS Type,
       (SELECT Data
               FROM table AS t2
               WHERE (ProblemID = t1.ProblemID) AND (FIELDID = 284)) AS Amount
FROM            table AS t1
WHERE        (FIELDID = 283)
GROUP BY ProblemID, Data
```

There, corrected

Comment: Thank you. got the query

SELECT ProblemID, Data AS Type,(SELECT Data FROM table AS t2 WHERE (ParamID = t1.ParamID + 1)) AS Amount FROM table AS t1 WHERE (FIELDID = 283)